# Error installing a pod - Bus Error at 0x00000001045b8000

Tags: ruby, xcode, cocoapods

I'm just learning to use cocoapods and am encountering an error when trying to install a pod.

Top of error:

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3/lib/ffi/library.rb:275: [BUG] Bus Error at 0x00000001045b8000
> ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.arm64e-darwin20]

Bottom of error:

> zsh: abort      pod install

Have tried the following, as suggested on some threads here and GitHub:

- Uninstalling and re-installing cocoapod
- sudo gem install xcodeproj
- sudo gem update

but nothing seems to be working; the error persists and the .xcworkspace file doesn't appear.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 193):

If the other solution (`sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`) does not work for you, try the following one instead:

`gem install --user-install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc`

After that, run `pod install` or whatever you were trying to do again, but without prefixing it with `arch -x86_64`.

It worked for me without issues and this way I could also avoid going the Intel emulation (Rosetta 2) way.

I find this solution in an [issue filed on the ffi github project](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/864).

Comment: Worked like a charm on M1 Max

Comment: Oh this should definitely be the top answer. This works like a charm, and doesn't require any emulation!

Comment: Worked on my M1 Pro as well. Did `gem install --user-install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc` and then normal `pod install` and compiled the project. All good.

Comment: Searched for hours to fix this issue, this finally fixed it (M1 Max). Thank you!

Comment: It worked for M1 pro as well. Thanks

Comment: It worked, in my case had to `pod repo update` after using the above commands.

Comment: This also works on M2 Air

Comment: If anyone having older `ffi` installed via `sudo gem install ffi` then have to uninstall that and run the above with `sudo` then it will works, thanks!

Comment: worked for M1 Max.. big thanks!

Comment: Works for M1, much appreciated!

Comment: Just the `--enable-libffi-alloc` flag is enough I think. `gem install ffi -v 1.14.0 -- --enable-libffi-alloc` worked for me on M3

Answer (score 37):

I came across someone having this issue a while ago and I believe one of the suggestions made was to try the following:

install gem using

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

and then run this

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

it might work, it might not, I'm not too sure.
This is because from the arm64 part of your error message I assume you have an M1 Mac. Either way it's probably worth a try.

Comment: I got an error when trying the first step: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/yaml.rb:3: warning: It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.

Comment: This looks like an issue with libyaml and ruby. Again, I'm not too experienced with working on cocoapods and programming with mac in general but try these steps below:

Step 1: brew install libyaml
(Check installation)
Step 2: brew info libyaml
(this should've brought up some text showing version number etc)
Step 3: try the above steps I've provided

If this works or doesn't work please let me know, as I'm learning as well Thanks.

Comment: In some case, run arch -x86_64 pod update to make app build on iOS simulator

Answer (score 27):

Reinstalling CocoaPods with `brew` and removing `ffi` gem solved the issue for me.

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall ffi
brew install cocoapods
pod install
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked.
Existing x86 version was creating issues

Comment: Also worked for me. I had existing x86 version clashing.

Comment: Worked for me on Macbook Pro 13" M2 chip

Comment: This worked well for me on a M1 mac! Looks like I had multiple ffi's installed that was causing issues.