# Cocoapod error, tried to install all the possible way on M1

Tags: cocoapods, react-native-ios, apple-m1

I get this error

```
Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template.
Please try again manually: "cd ./test/ios && pod install".
CocoaPods documentation: https://cocoapods.org/
```

When try to install manually i get this error,

```
oadError - dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb:5:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:284:in `ensure_versions_file_loaded'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:208:in `search'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `block in search'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `select'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `search'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:416:in `create_set_from_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:385:in `find_cached_set'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:360:in `specifications_for_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:165:in `search_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:274:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:60:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:77:in `with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:59:in `sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:754:in `push_state_for_requirements'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:288:in `push_initial_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:210:in `start_resolution'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:168:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=dlopen%28%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.4%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%2C+9%29%3A+no+suitable+image+found.++Did+find%3A%0A%09%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.4%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%3A+mach-o%2C+but+wrong+architecture%0A%09%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.4%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%3A+mach-o%2C+but+wrong+architecture+-+%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.4%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 31):

hi this fixed my issue

in a terminal

**sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi**

in the project root

**cd ios && arch -x86_64 pod install && cd ../**

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me! Do I have to do it for every Flutter project now?

Comment: Thanks!!! It did work, I was trying for 2 days, but your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else struggling with this issue, I just found a way to solve it. In addition to running terminal with Rosetta:

1. Right-click on Terminal in Finder
2. Get Info
3. Open with Rosetta

I installed a gem that seems to be related to the symbol not found in the error:

`sudo gem install ffi`

After doing this, cocoapods runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the podfile inside the ios folder and uncomment the line that says platform :ios, '9.0' and set it to platform :ios, '10.0'. MacBook Pro M1

Answer (score 0):

[Sebastián López post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69077289/19086322)

This worked for me on Mac.
Now command **`npx cap update ios`** work correctly.

A thousand thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall ffi
brew install cocoapods
pod install
```

Source :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72312058/9571770